# Why is the motion of a spring-mass system SHM?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I know it fits the conditions of SHM, such as a mass that oscillates, equilibrium position and restoring force, but specifically why does a spring have SHM? Is a reason that there is no lagging motion towards the end of the spring as seen in a paper clip chain?

Comment: *there is no lagging motion towards the end of the spring as seen in a paper clip chain* - What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

We call Simple Harmonic Motion (SHM) a motion that satisfies this differential equation:

$$\frac{d^2}{dt} x(t) + \omega^2\cdot x(t) = 0 $$

This holds for an ideal spring satisfying Newton's laws, because

$F=-k x$ and $F$ is also mass times acceleration, so

$$m a = -kx$$

represents the same equation with $\omega$ such that $k=m\omega^2$.

So, regarding your question, a spring satisfies this equation as long as we can model it as $F=-kx$

In other words, a SHM is a motion caused by a force of the type $F=-kx$.

Real spring-mass systems do not behave like this exactly, but it is a good approximation. This is called Hooke's law for springs.

Comment: Could you also say something explicit about this part of the question: *"there is no lagging motion towards the end of the spring"* ?

Comment: Ok so my classmates and I were told that the motion of a paperclip chain is not completely SHM because the last few clips at the bottom lag

Comment: @PM2Ring I could if I understood what you guys mean haha

Comment: To be honest, I'm not completely sure what Gabrielle means, either. ;) But I think they're talking about a time delay in the response of the system due to the finite speed that a pulse travels through the spring.

Comment: That is a longitudinal wave, isn't it? It travels with velocity $v=\frac{\lambda}{T}$

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain with physics.The restoring force  is proportional  to the displacement ($F_r=-kx$).But also its inertia try to keep on(Newton's First law).So motion inertia try the body deviate from it's original position to a displaced maximum  position then restoring force try to go back in original position in reverse direction. So this process go on and on and performing SHM.